# How to add a 'News' section to specific posts in WordPress

Tags: posts, categories, permalinks, url-rewriting, urls

I have a question regarding the WP post structure.

How can I add "News" or "Technology" to specific posts in WordPress? I think this technique is very different from "post category" as categories are added to every post.

Example:

mydomain.com/news/twitter-down-not-working

mydomain.com/news/technology/google-launches-pixel-3xl-phone

Comment: What are "_News_" and "_Technology_"? Are these custom categories (custom taxonomy)? Only an additional string in the link? Or maybe something else?

Comment: I think they are the only additional string in the link. Have a look at this URL. https://www.greaterkashmir.com/news/world/any-misadventure-by-pakistan-army-will-be-repelled-with-punitive-response-army-chief/

Comment: "_add `News` or `Technology` to **specific posts** (...)_".  Does it mean that selected posts should have a different link structure ( e.g. `news/category-name/special-post-name` ), and other posts different ( e.g. `news/post-name` )?  Or should the link always contain a category name?

Comment: Yes, Sir, I want to create a different URL structure for selected posts only. (e.g _news/post-name_  OR _news/category-name/special-post-name_) and other posts should have a simple URL structure (e.g _example.com/post-name_)